# Xcode 8.2 Beta instruments not recording any classes from iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm trying to debug a memory leak, but it appears that instruments is broken in Xcode 8.2. I've tried with two different projects. In the first project profiling allocations in instruments works fine and I can see the classes from the project in the list of memory allocations.

In the second project the classes from the project don't appear. Even when I can see their UIView's in the simulator. Nor do any of the classes from the APIs that the projects uses appear in the list. I have the allocations instrument set to log everything.

I'm at a lose to explain why instruments is not logging the classes from my app.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be the problem? or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimenting this seems to be caused by the Address Sanitizer. Turning it off enabling allocation recording again.